# What is the difference between PRAM and multi threading?

Tags: ds.algorithms

PRAM and multi-threading are somewhat part of the same model of the shared memory model, in which both can compute in parallel, and both can allow processors to communicate with each other since there data parallel.

So what is the difference between multithreading and PRAM?